# NHibernate: Is it okay to leave using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()){} without Commit() during read?

Tags: nhibernate

Quick question.. In a function that checks if a certain Terminal Id is available, is it okay for me to do it as below?

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    return ((new TerminalDAO(sm.Session)).Get(tid) == null) ? true : false;
}
```

Or is it advisable to do it with the Commit()?

```
Terminal terminal = null;
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    terminal = (new TerminalDAO(session)).Get(tid);
    tx.Commit();
}
return (terminal == null) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *readonly* operations - I would firstly appreciate you, that you did included transaction even for *readonly* operation - and also suggest to use a *rollback* and in fact the **explicit rollback**.

Please check these:

- [Is it a better practice to explicitly call transaction rollback or let an exception trigger an implicit rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418992/)
- [Do I need to call rollback if I never commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971903/)

My reason for **explicit `Rollback()`** would be:

1. Why **rollback**? We know it is READ, any accidental WRITE is not intended
2. Why **explicit**? Anyone coming later can **see** it. Self-describing code is the way. Relying on *defaults* could *later* lead to unexpected behaviour *(e.g. vendor changed the defaults)*

Comment: Thanks for the response! So the latter is good enough? (after replacing tx.Commit() with tx.RollBack())

Comment: I would never let the transaction without explicit commit or rollback so YES: tx.RollBack() is the way I would go... And the most important reason is: it is visible, when you come after a week, month... you will still see the Rollback.. do not have to think: what is the default here?

Comment: Be careful when using this approach in conjunction with second level caching: http://ayende.com/blog/3799/nh-prof-documentation-transaction-and-the-second-level-cache